# Keycloak creates an extra AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie with a path of "/auth" when logging in

Tags: keycloak

The Keycloak server sends what appears to be an extra AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie with a path value of "/auth" when logging into the console.

I am running Keycloak 3.4.3 Final, Standalone HA configuration on Windows 2016 servers which sit behind an F5 load balancer.

When this cookie appears in the browser and the user logs in/out of the console without closing the browser, it will eventually lead to Keycloak prompting the user with a warning "You took too long to login. Login process starting from beginning."  After the user logs in for the second time, occasionally, the browser will hit a "Too Many Redirects" error and fail to open the console.

Is Keycloak supposed to create two AUTH_SESSION_ID cookies, one with a path of "/auth" and the other with a path of my realm ("/auth/realms/xxxx")?

How are these symptoms related?

Comment: The main question is:  Is Keycloak supposed to create two AUTH_SESSION_ID cookies for a single session?

Comment: Note: the extra cookie confuses the F5 Load Balancer when using "Universal Persistence", which is trying to select which node to direct the user based on the AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie, but is expecting the auth cookie to be unique per user.

Comment: Update: If we only run a single node, we don't get the extra AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie, and we don't experience any of the subsequent symptoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, we should not get two AUTH_SESSION_ID cookies.

Thanks to Martin Kanis and the RedHat team as they identified why this was happening. If you are using F5 or another load balancer and not the mod_cluster balancer, you should **not** include the following setup in your configuration:

```
<session-cookie name="AUTH_SESSION_ID" http-only="true" />
```

They are going to update the Keycloak documentation and make this point clear.

Comment: Hi @Smallwood19, I'm seeing the exact same problem with Keycloak 4.5.0 here (multiple AUTH_SESSION_ID cookies, confused load balancer, endless redirects). Could you elaborate where your extra AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie came from, and how you got rid of it?

Comment: I wasn't given specifics by the RedHat team as to why or how the error occurs.  I assume the extra cookie is created by the Keycloak or JBoss system.  I got rid of the cookie by editing the configuration (e.g. standalone-ha.xml, domain.xml) and removing the line of XML shown above (<session-cookie name="AUTH_SESSION_ID" http-only="true" />) and restarting Keycloak.  Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It turned out that in our case, additional AUTH_SESSION_ID cookie was created by the load balancer. It was configured to use that cookie for session stickiness and created it when the original request didn't have it. Keycloak then added its own cookie by the same name, and everyone got confused..

Comment: Hello, I am using keycloak 5.0.0, there is no `<session-cookie name="AUTH_SESSION_ID" http-only="true" />` in standalone-ha.xml nor domain.xml but I am having the same issue.

Comment: Even I'm facing same issue with keyloak 11.0.2 version. there is no <session-cookie name="AUTH_SESSION_ID" http-only="true" /> in standalone-ha.xml nor domain.xml